# How to use Branches and Labels to seperate work

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, azure-devops, tfvc

I have Visual Studio 2015 and I've got a Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO) account which is like the TFS that I never got to use.

Here is my issue I am a little lost when it comes to allocating work to specific people.

I working with different people all over the Globe and I want to allocated just one area of my application to be worked on and have it to where not one person I am working with can see all the code, only the code they need. Especially when we start talking about configuration files, I am a little worried.

From my understanding you can create a branch and only add those programs that need to be worked on that is allocated to a specific person or company, and in another branch only allocate just the Web application portion, and in another branch only have the front end "browser" where the web designer works.

When I just added a branch, I copied all of the source files to this branch and it did not name it what I wanted it to be, I've got it highlighted and you can see it says Trunk-Branch, I want it to be relevant named like Sandbox, because I need to allocate just one program that is called sandbox.

From what I've read the tree goes like main -> test - > Dev "<-Sandbox I want"
                                               test - > Dev "<-Web App I want"

If only those apps are isolated they must inherit, I am assuming, from other references in the entire solution.

Is it normal to copy the entire base source code to each Dev?

And obliviously I did not get it right this time because the branch is right under trunk and I would have thought it would have been and offset a little to the right in a tree fashion.

I the examples I've seen it says main, well my main is Trunk.

Can someone give me a simple 1,2,3 answer to this it cannot be that difficult because there is not enough options. I am just lost because of all the examples are TFS and not VSO there is a little difference in the how-tos.

Can someone help me out be looking at my snap shots and tell me what to do here. All I want to do is create a base source and then create isolated DEV projects for separate people to work on.

With a little explaining I can get this right away, but I need expert help for sure.

Hope someone can help on this one, I really will be thankful!

[image: I created a branch and it added all the source files, I want only a few files]

[image: I picked branch which one should I have picked?]

[image: This is exactly what I am going for]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't branch an application, you branch a folder which may contain one or many applications.

If your applications are largely independent of one another, it makes sense to create branches per-application. Ex:

```
App 1
    Main
    Dev
App 2
    Main
    Dev
```

etc.

If your applications are interrelated and share significant amounts of code, it probably makes more sense to branch them all as a single unit:

```
Main
    App 1
    App 2
Dev
    App 1
    App
```

If the only goal is to restrict access by third parties to certain areas of your source tree, you can accomplish that without branches by using security settings at the individual folder level to lock the third party out of areas they shouldn't be in (or, conversely, to grant them access to the areas they should have access to, with the default being restricted access).

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, I get more out of that than a book! ;) Yes the goal is that I am working with different individuals and companies on specific parts of the solution with well over 50 programs. Let me ask you this is it possible to give access to a program that has db connection strings in it and restrict the cnn.config files? And what are label for?

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com You can set read permissions on an individual file. Labels are just for marking a specific revision of code. So if you do a release of, say, version 3.2, you can label the set of source code that results in that particular build of software so that you can retrieve and debug version 3.2 if you ever need to do so.

Comment: You the boss! I've spent a lot of time with it and I am starting to get the gist of this it really is very simple when you got help.... thanks!